I want adapter to not automatically detect installed wallet and show only Phantom if both of Solflare and Phantom are installed
I have installed both of Phantom and Solflare.
If I use @solana/wallet-adapter-react to select/connect wallet, adapter automatically detects Phantom and Solflare both.
But I want to hide Solflare, and show only Phantom wallet in the screen.
Is it possible?
Please tell me how to show certain wallets only in the screen even though it is installed on the browser.

Sure, But you will need to add custom logic to your wallet list component/function.
function WalletList() {
    const { wallets, select } = useWallet();

    const installedWallets = wallets.filter(
        (wallet) => wallet.readyState === "Installed"
    );

    return (
        <section>
            {installedWallets.length === 0 && (
                <section>
                    Please Install a Compatible Solana wallet to continue
                </section>
            )}

            {installedWallets
                .filter((wallet) => wallet.adapter.name === "Phantom")
                .map((wallet) => (
                <WalletItem
                    key={wallet.adapter.name}
                    name={wallet.adapter.name}
                    iconSrc={wallet.adapter.icon}
                    connect={() => select(wallet.adapter.name)}
                />
            ))}
            </section>
    );
}

reference -> https://github.com/jim4067/yet-another-solana-ui-template/blob/3236833a7e01407c8057fde46aea14f295122a97/app/ui/components/nav/ConnectBtn.tsx#L84-L118

Should customize existing npm module?

not sure I understand? customize in what way?

where can I edit WalletList function?

check the link I shared
